# OpenCart bug shows Free Shipping for UNDER the price that qualifies free shipping

Tags: opencart

I setup OpenCart 1.5.5.1 to use free shipping for orders of $50.00+ however when I have $49.99 or lower the free-shipping is *incorrectly still an option*.

How do I hide the free-shipping for the price under the qualifying price?

Yes, I've changed the order.

Yes, both flat and free shipping are enabled.

Yes, I've checked the *catalog\model\shipping\free.php* file to ensure the code is correct AFAICT...

```
<?php
class ModelShippingFree extends Model {
    function getQuote($address) {
        $this->language->load('shipping/free');

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "zone_to_geo_zone WHERE geo_zone_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('free_geo_zone_id') . "' AND country_id = '" . (int)$address['country_id'] . "' AND (zone_id = '" . (int)$address['zone_id'] . "' OR zone_id = '0')");

        if (!$this->config->get('free_geo_zone_id')) {
            $status = true;
        } elseif ($query->num_rows) {
            $status = true;
        } else {
            $status = false;
        }

        if ($this->cart->getSubTotal() < $this->config->get('free_total')) {
            $status = false;
        }

        $method_data = array();

        if ($status===true) {
            $quote_data = array();

            $quote_data['free'] = array(
                'code'         => 'free.free',
                'title'        => $this->language->get('text_description'),
                'cost'         => 0.00,
                'tax_class_id' => 0,
                'text'         => $this->currency->format(0.00)
            );

            $method_data = array(
                'code'       => 'free',
                'title'      => $this->language->get('text_title'),
                'quote'      => $quote_data,
                'sort_order' => $this->config->get('free_sort_order'),
                'error'      => false
            );
        }

        return $method_data;
    }
}
?>
```

What else can I do besides file a bug complaint with OpenCart?

Comment: Is it possible that one number is ex-tax and the other inc-tax?

Comment: Please, check this code: `if ($this->cart->getSubTotal() < $this->config->get('free_total')) {
            $status = false;
        }` and find out, what value is returned by this call `$this->config->get('free_total')` - I guess it won't be `50`...

Answer (score 0):

OpenCart does not validate that the fields are integers, so removing the $ symbol from the free-shipping value fixed the issue.